AWS Firehose Partition key's value should not be null or empty
In Firehose data is coming from Kinesis Stream. I am using data transformation in firehose so that I can use in dynamic partitioning and put the data in s3 folder wise (tableName) because the data is coming from multiple tables but using this lambda for transformation is showing an error in firehose that partition key's value should not be null when I am using
partitionKeyFromQuery:customPrefix

I have checked the customprefix name is printing correctly in lambda:
for record in event['records']:
    # Decode the Kinesis base64 data
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(decoded_data)

    # I am only processing deleted records for backup
    if data.get('eventName') == 'REMOVE':

        table_name = data.get('tableName')  # Extract table name 

        # Construct the S3 prefix using the table name
        new_prefix = table_name
        print(new_prefix)
        # Transform the data for REMOVE event
        transformed_data = json.dumps(data)

        # Append the transformed record, including the custom S3 prefix in metadata
        output.append({
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(transformed_data.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'),
            'metadata': {
                'partitionKeys': {
                    'customPrefix': new_prefix  # Custom S3 prefix based on table name
                }
            }
        })
    else:
        # Drop any non-REMOVE events
        output.append({
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Dropped'
        })

Using this, I want to achieve separate folder of multiple tables inside my s3 bucket as backup from firehose
